# How can I access an HTML element that is embedded in PHP echo, using PHP?

Tags: php, html

I need to access an HTML element with `name="account"`, but this is embedded inside PHP, and I can't see to find a way around this as I get an error on my webpage, "unidentified index: account" which I know means that it cannot find that element. I have done this same thing in the same project but not accessing the element from within PHP script.

The line of code from the "account" page that is causing the error: `$customerID = $_GET['account'];` where account is the HTML element I'm trying to access.

Below is the "echo" code on my index.php page where I am trying to access the button from.

```
    echo '<div style="float:right; width:
    <a href="account.php" style="display:inline-block;"><button type="submit" 
    name="account" class="glyphicon glyphicon-user btn btn-success" id="account">
    </button></a></div>';
```

It's quite difficult to explain but I hope there is enough information for someone to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code snipper to avoid the error `unidentified index: account`

```
$customerID = isset($_GET['account']) ? $_GET['account'] : '';
```

Here `isset` checking if the values defined on the index `account`, you were getting the error because there is no index with name `account` in `$_GET`.Add an isset check before running the code, that will prevent any errors

For more details [isset](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

Comment: that does work thank you, but can you explain a little more as to what that does?